# Delimited field not taken into account with VBA Excel SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a  test text file named `test.txt` with the following lines :

```
Contract ID!cash
1!15
2!10
3!20
3!10
```

placed in a given directory with an Excel file.

When I am running the following SQL query put on my Excel file, `FMT=Delimited(!)` seems to produce no result.
The query sticks to the default `,` parameter to delimit the different columns and I would like to know why.

```
Sub 

QueryTextFile()

    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim str As String

    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    cnn.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    cnn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & ";" & _
                            "Extended Properties = 'text;FMT=Delimited(!)'"
    cnn.Open

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    str = "SELECT * FROM [test.txt]"

    rs.Open str, cnn

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
    cnn.Close

End Sub
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z37hU.png)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I believe you need to create schema.ini file.

Comment: Tank you for your help, that works.
However, how come that 'Extended Properties' with appropriate commands does not produce the expected effect?